# I move to next hostel. I try login to network, but in Firefox / Chromium don't show to me that option. I get connection with network device, IP DNS

Tags: networking, firefox, dns

I move to next hostel.
I try login to network, but in Firefox / Chromium don't show to me that option.
I get connection with network device, IP and look good.
Firefox / Chromium can't open websites and login to network, VPNs can't login too, ping to domains don't works.

I check resolve and other configs for network with backup and is that same what was.

Someone have idea what can happend?

Thanks for answers.

config check, compare config with backup, delete network WiFi connection and restart system.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Not really sure what version of Ubuntu you are using, but most hotels/hostels usually can give you a webpage of theirs to log into to activate the internet.  But please clean up your question and add details of your system and how you are trying to connect.  Thank you!

Comment: If you think you're not getting the captive portal webpage, try http://neverssl.com to force your browser to bring it up.

Comment: 22.04 LTS. That webpage don't Showup.

Comment: Check if others around you can successfully connect. Check if anyone else around you has a similar problem. Some-can-connect (but others not) may have many possible causes, many of which are on the network side.

Comment: Only I have that a problem.

Comment: Neverssl don't works.

Comment: I use AP IP I'm browser and I see diagnostic informationa. Everything is good.

Comment: I turn off adds and protection in FF, firewall. Nothing happend.

Comment: Nowone have an idea what's so about?!

Comment: We have no control over the way that hotels / hostels do their WiFi networks, so we can only guess as to why you are not working.  Like I pointed out before you should check with the place you are staying about what page you need to go to to login to their network.  We cannot tell you what page they use.

Comment: That is bigger company and I was in other places and works good.

Comment: So, that is telling me then that your installation is good and your network is working fine.  Your issue that you are bumping into is the place that you are going to.  There is absolutely nothing that we can do to help you.

Comment: Cisco Meraci Cloud

Comment: Turn off VPN solve a problem.